# How to show $\int_{0}^{+\infty} d x \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}}=\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{2}} $ with residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the following integral using the residue theorem.
$$
I=\int_{0}^{+\infty} d x \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}}=\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{2}}
$$
But somehow I'm not getting the correct results, and I was hoping you could help spot where things go wrong? Because I have looked it through several times and can't seem to find anything wrong. Here is my approach:

---

Define: $$
f(z)=\frac{(z)^{1 / 2}}{\left(z^{2}+1\right)^{2}}=\frac{(z)^{1 / 2}}{(z+i)^{2}(z-i)^{2}}
$$

f has poles of 2nd order at $z=\pm i$.
And it has a branch point at $z=0$. Maintaining $f$ as a single-valued function is fairly easy, if I define $z=|z|e^{i\theta} $ and restrict $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

I want to integrate $f$ over the following contour:
[image]

$$
\oint f(z) d z=\int_{\Gamma^-} f(z) d z+\int_{c_{r}} f(z) d z+\int_{\Gamma^{+}} f(z) d z+\int_{C_{R}} f(z) d z=2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}(f, z=i)
$$

The integral along the infinite halfcircle ($C_R$ where $R\rightarrow \infty$) converges to zero. The same goes for the infinitesimal circle $c_r$ as $r\rightarrow 0$.

The parametrization of $\Gamma^+$ gives the integral we are trying to solve:
$$
\int_{\Gamma^{+}} f(z) d z=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}} d x=I
$$

If we want to parametrize $\Gamma^-$ we can set $z=xe^{i\pi}$ and $dz=-dx$ and integrate from $-\infty$ to $0$:
$$
\int_{\Gamma^-} f(z) d z=\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{x^{1 / 2} e^{i \pi / 2}}{\left(x^{2} e^{2 i \pi}+1\right)^{2}}(-d x)
$$ but substituting $x=-u$ and $dx=-du$, changing sign of limits and reversing the limits ends up being equivalent with
$$
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(u\right)^{1 / 2}}{\left(u^{2}+1\right)^{2}} d u=I
$$

Calculating the residue of the enclosed pole:
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f, z=i)=\lim _{z \rightarrow i}\left[\frac{d}{d z}(z-i)^{2} f(z)\right]=\lim _{z \rightarrow i}\left[\frac{d}{d z} \frac{z^{1 / 2}}{(z+i)^{2}}\right]=\frac{e^{-i \pi / 4}}{8}=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i\right)
$$

Which ends up giving:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Rightarrow \oint f(z) d z=2 I=2 \pi i \frac{1}{8}(1-i) \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
&\Rightarrow I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)} d x=\frac{\pi}{8} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i(1-i)=\frac{\pi}{8} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)
\end{aligned}
$$
Which of course isn't quite right.

Comment: When you make half-turn (going along the big circle of radius $R\to\infty$) $ x\to xe^{i\pi}$ and $\sqrt x\to \sqrt xe^{i\pi/2}$. But when you integrate next along $\Gamma^{-}$ , $x$ changes from $+\infty$ to $0$, not from $-\infty$. You get $\int_{\Gamma^{-}} =-e^{\pi i/2}\int_R^0\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2}dx=i\int_0^R\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2}dx$, and, together with $\Gamma^{-}$, $I(1+i)=2\pi i Res_{z=i/2}\frac{\sqrt z}{(1+z^2)^2}=2\pi i\frac{d}{dz}\frac{\sqrt z}{(z+i)^2}|_{z=i}=2\pi i\frac{i-3z}{2\sqrt z (z+i)^3}|_{z=i}=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt 2}(1+i) \Rightarrow I=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt 2}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Okay, thank you! Is it possible you can clarify why x changes from $+\infty$? I mean it makes sense when you consider it as a radius since a radius has to be positive.

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out. I try to use the same approach as when I do line integrals with vector functions. But in that case I would do this type of integration by setting the position vector $\pmb{r}=x \hat{x}$ and $d\pmb{r}=dx \hat{x}$ and integrate from $x=-\infty$ to $0$.  So if I want to use the same approach, I should just set z=x

Comment: If you operate in the complex plane, you should care about the change of variables, because you also change the integration path in the complex plane. For example, you cannot simply make the change $x=-y$ - opposite to the change of variable in R.

Answer (score 1):

It is practical to perform the substitution $x\mapsto z^2$ in order to get, by parity

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{z^2}{(z^4+1)^2}\,dz. $$
It is also practical to perform a step of integration by parts, by reading the integrand function as $\frac{1}{4z}\cdot\frac{4z^3}{(z^4+1)^2}$ and by taking $\frac{1}{z^4+1}-1 = -\frac{z^4}{z^4+1}$ as a primitive of $\frac{4z^3}{(z^4+1)^2}$. The outcome is
$$ I = \frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{z^2}{z^4+1}\,dz=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)^2+2} $$
which by Glasser's master theorem equals
$$ \frac{1}{4}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dt}{t^2+2} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}}.$$